Identify first constant value within a period in R tidyverse
Given a dataframe (df) with item_id and price, I would like to obtain the first price that is constant i.e., lasts for a period of at least 90 days for each item (item_id), when available. Am stuck on this.
Each item is available on the market from the season_start until season_end where each row can be loosely thought of as a "season", and multiple rows can make up a period - where we can check if price was constant.
Example: For the item_id = 1, the first non-missing price is 450, and comes from the season_start date "2022-06-15", however that "season" is less than 90 days (season_end - season_start). But the next two rows/seasons after it have similar price and the period covered by these 3 rows is more than 90 days (season_end (row3) - season_start (row1), making the price of 450 the first constant value within a 90 days period for this item which is the desired result and can be added to the dataframe in variable first_constant_price.
One might start like this so that records are properly ordered from the earliest (season_start) per item. Then the rest follows... Shall greatly appreciate tidyverse-styled solutions.
df %>% 
group_by(item_id) %>% 
arrange(season_start, .by_group = TRUE)  

Below is an example dataset.
df <- structure(list(item_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 27, 27,
                                 
                                 27, 27, 27, 27, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 158, 158, 158,
                                 
                                 158, 158), season_end = structure(c(19173, 19173, 19265, 19357,
                                                                     
                                                                     19447, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19722, 18992, 18992, 19082, 19173,
                                                                     
                                                                     19265, 19357, 19265, 19265, 19447, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19630,
                                                                     
                                                                     19630, 19538, 19538, 19538, 19630, 19630), class = "Date"), season_start = structure(c(19157,
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            19158, 19158, 19158, 19398, 19398, 19494, 19592, 19662, 18973,
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            18974, 19013, 19013, 19013, 19013, 19259, 19263, 19388, 19438,
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                            19534, 19541, 19541, 19599, 19522, 19522, 19529, 19541, 19613
                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                     ), class = "Date"), price = c(NA, 450, 450, 450, NA, 1050, 450,
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   150, NA, NA, 150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 150, 100, 50, 20, 20,
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   20, 40, NA, 700, 300, 600, 900)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df",
                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))

Here is the desired results
desired_result_df <- structure(list(item_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 27, 27, 
                                                27, 27, 27, 27, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 158, 158, 158, 
                                                158, 158), season_end = structure(c(19173, 19173, 19265, 19357, 
                                                                                    19447, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19722, 18992, 18992, 19082, 19173, 
                                                                                    19265, 19357, 19265, 19265, 19447, 19447, 19538, 19630, 19630, 
                                                                                    19630, 19538, 19538, 19538, 19630, 19630), class = "Date"), season_start = structure(c(19157, 
                                                                                                                                                                           19158, 19158, 19158, 19398, 19398, 19494, 19592, 19662, 18973, 
                                                                                                                                                                           18974, 19013, 19013, 19013, 19013, 19259, 19263, 19388, 19438, 
                                                                                                                                                                           19534, 19541, 19541, 19599, 19522, 19522, 19529, 19541, 19613
                                                                                    ), class = "Date"), price = c(NA, 450, 450, 450, NA, 1050, 450, 
                                                                                                                  150, NA, NA, 150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 150, 100, 50, 20, 20, 
                                                                                                                  20, 40, NA, 700, 300, 600, 900), id = 1:28, first_constant_price = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       450, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))




Is that desired result dataset correct? You have marked row 20, but that's just a 5-day period (assuming both start & end dates are inclusive) and there are no overlaps. Though row 21 seems viable candidate. But if it is, then why omit row 27 where dates are identical to row 21?

Thanks @margusl I marked row 20 because it is the first in a series (3 subsequent rows) of where price = 20, and this starts on season_start = "2023-06-26" and ends in season_end = ''2023-09-30" - a time difference of 96 days. Apologies for not being clear.

So gaps between season are fine?

Yes, as long as the series of rows with price are the same price. Any price interruption with a different price in between for example  is what is not fine.

A tidyverse solution
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, item_id) |> 
  arrange(season_start, .by_group = TRUE) |> 
  mutate(
    season_length = season_end - season_start,
    price_group = consecutive_id(price)
    ) |> 
  group_by(item_id, price_group, price) |> 
  summarise(season_length = sum(season_length)) |> 
  group_by(item_id) |> 
  filter(!is.na(price), season_length >= 90) |> 
  summarise(price = first(price))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   item_id [3]
#>   item_id price
#>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       1   450
#> 2      27    50
#> 3      32    20

With explanation:
# Arrange each item's prices by date
group_by(df, item_id) |> 
  arrange(season_start, .by_group = TRUE) |> 

  mutate(
    ## Calculate length of season
    season_length = season_end - season_start,
   
    ## dplyr::consecutive_id() lets us assign the same
    ## value to rows with consecutive prices
    price_group = consecutive_id(price)
    ) |> 

  ## Get total days that each price remains 'fixed'
  group_by(item_id, price_group, price) |> 
  summarise(season_length = sum(season_length)) |> 

  ## Drop missing prices, keep only consistent periods > 90
  group_by(item_id) |> 
  filter(!is.na(price), season_length >= 90) |> 

  ## Get first price that meets our criteria
  summarise(price = first(price))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   item_id [3]
#>   item_id price
#>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       1   450
#> 2      27    50
#> 3      32    20

Created on 2024-12-03 with reprex v2.1.1
